# User Reputation Page Not Reporting Correctly

Tags: bug

On the [Users page](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) if you look at the points under the monthly link, it shows the points for top point getters is greatly exaggerated. Look at dlu's points, which is shows 2591 for the month, yet if you look at his points actually earned for the month, is something like 250. Here are some screen caps of what I'm talking about:

[image]

**dlu's user page on Activity/Reputation**

[image]

Comment: It's *almost* explainable by caching except not really: The week tab is correct and it's like the month tab didn't notice that August started. That's the correct total if you count *July* 1 to today (Aug 11). I haven't found anything on MSE about this *yet* but I'll keep looking. I'll also see if I can interrogate employees and find something out.

Comment: @JasonC - I didn't realize it could be the combination of July/August, but the discrepancy of mine showing the right amount is a little weird.

Comment: Check it out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281997/something-wrong-with-month-user-rep-some-users-show-quarterly-figures - You're not the only one that noticed. Seems to be recent.

Comment: @JasonC - So I'm not going crazy ... that's good, lol. It looks like it's SE wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So [here's the skinny, mostly](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/august-users-page-hiccup):

- Reputation on the users page is normally calculated on a cumulative basis (for performance), and that total is explicitly reset to 0 by some background job every week / month / quarter / year.
- For some reason that job didn't run this month (August 2016) on this site, and [<s>possibly others</s> everywhere else](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5176179#5176179). If you look at dlu's rep history, for example, the total displayed is actually their total from *July* 1st to today (August 11th).
- Things that force a full rep recalc for a user should correct their number on the user's page. I don't know off the top of my head what does this but it's usually various types of events. For example, if dlu were to delete then undelete one of his own posts, I believe that would trigger the recalc and then the users page would be correct.
- It doesn't affect *every* user, since users whose reputation has gone through a full recalc will have correct values on that page. That's why e.g. yours is correct but dlu's isn't.
- [You are not alone,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281997/something-wrong-with-month-user-rep-some-users-show-quarterly-figures) and there is now an answer there explaining the issue.

It <s>should theoretically be fixed tomorrow morning by an update script scheduled just to solve this month's issue. If that doesn't work or they don't get around to it, then it</s> should be good again come September 1st. So, it's not normal but it hasn't gone unnoticed.

Comment: It's been noticed and that's all which really matters. Thanks for digging this all up! :o)

Comment: They must have run an intermediate script on this, because it appears things are fixed, at least for this site.